# I can not display Django form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a contact form but it's html template does not see {{ form }} template. What am I doing wrong? Where is an error.

My code is attached above.

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
 listing = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 listing_id = models.IntegerField()
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 email = models.EmailField()
 phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 message = models.TextField(blank=True)
 file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
 contact_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
 user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)


 def __str__(self):
     return self.name

 def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('listings', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In views.py file

```
class ContactCreate(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'listing.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
       path('listings/<int:pk>/', views.ContactCreate.as_view(), name='contact-create')
]
```

html

```
    <form action="{% url 'contact-create' pk=listing.pk %}" method="post">
       
        {{ form }}
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary">
    </form>
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name','email','phone','file']
```

Could you help me out, please

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a `form_class` with `ContactForm`, Django is expecting a form to be provided so you have two options:

Create a form.py and add the following:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Don't forget to add that to your view:

```
from myapp.forms import ContactForm
```

If you want your custom form to be display you have to specify the `form_class` in your create view:

```
form_class = ContactForm
```

If you are using a custom template to display your form add the following to your create view:

```
template_name = 'listing.html' # or the path to your template
```

Comment: I have forms.py file, forgot to write it. I corrected the question. But the form  is still not displaying. I can't understand where is the errror

Comment: there is "from .forms import ContactForm" in my views.py file

Comment: @Юрий1982 see edit from my question, you have to add the form_class to your create view

Comment: I added it but nothing chaged - class ContactCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    model = Contact

Comment: what is the name of template where the form is showing up ?

Comment: The tamplate name is listing.html

Comment: Then you are using a custom template, see my edit, you have to add ``template_name``

Comment: I added nothing changed . Corrected my question with all addings

Comment: Why are you using ``form_class = ContactForm``inside your form ?

Comment: it's in views.py  I removed from forms.py file but no changes